# Simple query hangs PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table "the_table" with three fields: "id" (primary key), "a" and "b". I need select for each "a" the row where "b" has max value for that "a". Then I run the query:

```
select x.a, x.id
from the_table x
where b = ( select max( b ) where a = x.a )
```

This query hangs my PostgreSQL server.

I tried another query:

```
select x.a, max( x.id )
from the_table x
where b = ( select max( b ) where a = x.a )
group by x.a
```

But the result is the same.

What is wrong in these queries?

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: No FROM clause in the sub-query?

Comment: @jarlh Would it even run with that syntax?

Comment: It doesn't hang, it waits for the rest of the query  because you have not terminated it yet with a semi-colon.

Comment: You are missing a `;` at the end of your statement. If you are using `psql` note that the prompt changed indicating that the statement is not finished and it's waiting for you to end it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see only one record for each value in "a" then 
Postgres has wonderfull DISTINCT ON clause for this.

```
select distinct on (a) id, a, b 
  from the_table t
 order by a, b desc, id
```

The order is important - first goes the list of your columns in "distinct on" clause - in your case just "a" column, then order your data how you want to see them - in your case you want to see max b so "b desc"

If you want to return all records where "b = max(b)" for "a" then

```
select id, a, b
  from (select id, a, b, rank() over(partition by a order by b desc) rnk
          from the_table) a
 where rnk=1
```

And a good tip - NEVER, EVER use nested SELECTS in WHERE statements. 
If DB has more then few records you will wait for ages to see results if not something worse.

Comment: Thank You very much! I will use the first solution

Answer (score 0):

You would need a from clause in your subquery.

```
select x.a, x.id
from the_table x
where b = (select max( b ) from the_table x where a = x.a )
```

Comment: I am sorry. I simplified the query but have not tested it. The real query was: 

select ch.loan, max( ch.id )
 from cache_Loan_Sum_Per_Hour ch
 where stat_datetime = ( select max( stat_datetime ) from cache_Loan_Sum_Per_Hour where loan = ch.loan )  group by ch.loan

Comment: And the other query was:  

select ch.loan, ch.id
 from cache_Loan_Sum_Per_Hour ch
 where stat_datetime = (
  select max( stat_datetime )
  from cache_Loan_Sum_Per_Hour
  where loan = ch.loan
 )

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem with `alias` & of course `from` clause  :

```
select x.*
from the_table x
where x.b = ( select max(x1.b) from the_table x1 where x1.a = x.a );
```

And of course, if you want just maximum `id` rather than other information, then use `group by` clause instead :